# How IP scanners get address of inactive computers?

Tags: networking, ip, lan

I don't understand how IP scanners find out that a computer is on the network even when it is turned off, and they will also find out its MAC address. Because when I ping IP address of computer via command line is unreachable...

In Advanced IP Scanner Active computers have blue icon, inactive grey, but with info, and unassigned(unknown) IP address are grey without info...

Can some one explain me this magic?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it's likely querying DNS records on machines it CAN see on the domain, and gathering intel on the machines listed. e.g. `192.168.0.12` has a DNS record stating `192.168.0.26` is `Hostname B`, so the application lists that IP and hostname for information, even though `Hostname B` may be switched off when the scan runs.

Answer (score 0):

The majority of computers leave their wired network interface live even when turned off.  Easy test turn your computer off then look at the back and see if the network interface is still flashing!

Comment: This is true, but it does not explain why I can't get information about a computer on the network via the command line when it is turned off and the IP scanner can do it...